# OpenGL: Z-Index glitching

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm developing little game based on LWJGL (so Java). I'm rendering skybox (that darkblue somthing on image), that is constructed from 6 quads (GL_QUADS) and one box (white something), that is rendered using VBO.

Problem is, that white box is glitching (geometry is OK, but image in framebuffer is...). I dunno, how to find reason (depth testing, alpha, ...) I've tried someting (render ordering), but nothing helps.

Is render order important for objects, that are solid (opaque)?

[image: almost every frame glitch]

Answer (score 0):

It's typical. Lastly I tried to disabling features in renderer.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

This was that beast.... tfuj - I'm sorry for spam.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your box is too close to camera so it is cut buy near clip plane. Try decreasing the nearVal of glFrustum.